# Sorting Top 10 Listing Python

Tags: python, list

Hi I have been trying to figure out how to sort the list in reverse order and only have 10 items in the list. I am a very beginner and still trying to figure how listing works. Would appreciate your help.

```
scoring = {"Name": "", "WinStreak": 0}
leaderboard = []
count = 0

with open("testing2.txt", "r") as fileText:
    for line in fileText:
        name = line.split()[0]
        winning = int(line.split()[2])
        leaderboard.append({"Name": name, "WinStreak": winning})

for display in leaderboard:
    print(display["Name"], "-", display["WinStreak"])
```

*testing2.txt*

```
Cruz , 2
Cherryl , 3
Kim , 6
WyeKeong , 7
Johnny , 3
Chris , 6
Javier , 5
Alham , 7
XuanWei , 1
KiahYen , 3
YuZheng , 5
```

*Actual Output*

```
Cruz - 2
Cherryl - 3
Kim - 6
WyeKeong - 7
Johnny - 3
Chris - 6
Javier - 5
Alham - 7
XuanWei - 1
KiahYen - 3
YuZheng - 5
```

*Expected Output*

```
WyeKeong - 7
Alham - 7
Chris - 6
Kim - 6
Javier - 5
YuZheng - 5
Johnny - 3
Cherryl - 3
KiahYen - 3
Cruz - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to sort the dictionary based on the values. For that you can simply use -

```
leaderboard = sorted(leaderboard, key=lambda itm: itm["WinStreak"], reverse = True)
```

#### Here's how the above function works -

- the `sorted()` can take an **2nd argument which is the key** based on which it will sort the given data structure.
- In the key argument, we are passing an **lambda function** which will return the value(itm["WinStreak"]) from each key-value pair present in leaderboard.
- The `reverse=True` will sort it in descending pair(it is ascending, by default ).

So, This statement will sort the `leaderboard` based on the values they hold in descending order. After using this statement you can simply print as you did -

```
for display in leaderboard:
    print(display["Name"], "-", display["WinStreak"])
```

This will give you the required output. Hope this help !

Comment: It gives me an error stating " AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' "

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
for display in sorted(leaderboard, key=lambda x: x['WinStreak'], reverse=True)[:10]:
    print(display["Name"], "-", display["WinStreak"])
```

To break this down:

- `sorted` sorts the list in ascending order.  The `key` argument describes what part of each list item to sort by.  In this case, we want to sort by each player's `WinStreak` value.  `reverse` changes the sort to descending order.
- `[:10]` slices the result to take up to the first 10 elements.